# processing of page stops after response.writefile

Tags: c#, asp.net, response, export-to-excel

This question has been asked a number of times but still I am not able to find a proper solution to it. I have two questions.

I am creating an excel file, writing data to it and then rendering it to the user for download. I have used microsoft.interop for the same.

The first problem is:
I am trying to use a messagebox(javascript) to show how many rows were generated in the excel file after the user has downloaded the excel. This messagebox never shows, however the code is executed. How can i achieve this?

Secondly:
After the excel has been created, an excel.exe process keeps running in the task manager, even after i have manually cleaned up the references.

This alert box does not show after the file is rendered.

```
flag = WriteDatasetToExcel(ds);
            if (flag)
            {

                ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Javascript", "<script>alert('Number of rows generated : " + ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count + "')</script>");
            }
```

The relevant code is given

```
excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        excelwrkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(1);
        excelwrksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelwrkbook.Sheets[1];
        excelwrksheet.Name = "Application Data";
```

after writing data, saving and rendering is done like this:

```
excelwrkbook.SaveAs(filepath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, true, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, true);
        excelwrkbook.Close(0, 0, 0);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(filepath);
        excelApp.Quit();
        flag = true;
```

and now finally the cleanup code:

```
ReleaseObjects(excelrange);
        ReleaseObjects(excelwrksheet);
        ReleaseObjects(excelwrkbook);
        ReleaseObjects(excelApp);
```

the releaseobjects function is as follows:

```
private void ReleaseObjects(Object obj)
{
    if (obj != null && Marshal.IsComObject(obj))
    {
        while (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj) != 0) { }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all let me tell you that working in a web based environment with Microsoft Excel interop is not very efficient.

I use usually use the openXML approach for this needs. [here](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/11/19/7813.aspx)

for your first question:
Your response content type is application/vnd.ms-excel hence the browser will not execute any java script from this content. you must identify that the excel has been downloaded or make a prior call to get the rows and return the result in a java script or any other acceptable content type.

for your second question: just don't use it for web environment it was not designed for it.

Comment: I studied the link you mentioned, it is just another way of writing to excel. I have no problems doing that. 
I have tried calling the javascript prior but its still not showing anything.

and for your second answer: So is there any workaround for this? and do we have any sure shot way of knowing that all the references have been cleaned up ??

Comment: You must understand, the openXML just generates an XML file that is compatible with Excel. it is not a process that works in the background. you need to make an Ajax call to the server and return the number of rows then prompt the result to your client.

Comment: The thing is, I cannot use any third party thing in my code.

so if possible can you help me out without doing that.